Understanding the use of Indicator function
in my research work I came across following expression:
$A = \mathbb{P}[X\geq \tau_s, D\leq \frac{c}{2}(T_c-\frac{cT_c}{2B_s}), Y\geq \tau_c]$---(1)
where $\mathbb{P}$ denotes probability, $X,Y$ are random variables and all other things are constant.
$B =  \mathbb{P}[X \times \mathbb{1}(D\leq \frac{c}{2}(T_c-\frac{cT_c}{2B_s})) \geq \tau_s]$ $\times \mathbb{P}[Y\geq \tau_c] $---(2)
where $1(.)$ is an indicator function whose value is equal to 1 if the expression inside $Q$ is true else its value is 0.
My query is how indicator function is applicable in equation (2) or how equation (2) is obtained from equation (1).
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

$A=B$ is $X$ and $Y$ are independent . You didn't  mention independence.

The event $D\leq \frac{c}{2}(T_c-\frac{cT_c}{2B_s})$ does not involve any random variable. So you can prove $A=B$ by considering the cases $D\leq \frac{c}{2}(T_c-\frac{cT_c}{2B_s})$ and $D>  \frac{c}{2}(T_c-\frac{cT_c}{2B_s})$.
In the first case $A=P(X \ge \tau_s, Y\ge \tau_c)$ and $B=P(X \ge \tau_s) P(Y\ge \tau_c)$. So $A=B$ provided $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
In the second case $A=B=0$ (assuming that $\tau_s >0$).
[If the event $H$ is not random then $1_H=0$  or $1_H=1$ ].

I'd add that, provided $0<\tau_s$ , then ${X\geq\tau_s}\cap H = {X\cdot\mathbf 1(H)\geq\tau_s}$

@ geetha290krm, Thank u so much for ur reply....Yes $X$ and $Y$ are independent....But I am not getting how $\tau_s$ is included with indicator function of event $D\leq \frac{c}{2}(T_c-\frac{cT_c}{2B_s})$ in equation (2), when it ($\tau_s$) is not present with  event $D\leq \frac{c}{2}(T_c-\frac{cT_c}{2B_s})$ in equation (1)

@Heretolearn $\mathbb{1}(D\leq \frac{c}{2}(T_c-\frac{cT_c}{2B_s}))$ is  $1$ in the first case and $0$ in the second case. The exact value of $\tau_s$ does not come into the picture as long as $\tau_s >0$.

Ok...got it....
